# Session in Threads

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, session, httpcontext

I have an application that uses a thread to execute a process that generates a XML file at the end. This process takes a lots of time, and because of this, I created a progress bar outside the thread for each 0,5 seconds read a session variable that is set inside the thread. But, when I execute the application, without using breakpoints the following error is generated:

> Session state can only be used when enableSessionState is set to true, either in a configuration file or in the Page directive.
>
> Please also make sure that System.Web.SessionStateModule or a custom session state module is included in the `<configuration>\<system.web>\<httpModules>` section in the application configuration.

On other hand, when I execute the application with the breakpoints, it executes successfully.

I don't know how to make this work out without breakpoints.

The thread and the progress bar are in different .aspx files.

Thread Creation:

```
HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;
Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
{
    HttpContext.Current = ctx;
    GerarArquivosXML(DtArquivos, diretorioArquivos);
}));
thread.Start();
```

During the execution of the method "GerarArquivosXML" I try to add a value to a session variable:

```
Session.Add("Count", Progress.Count);
```

For example, if I put a breakpoint on the first line on page load and run it line by line, it works out. Without breakpoints, the application throws the exception, and crashes.

Comment: You shouldn't use new threads to generate the file, [it's dangerous](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx/). Much better solution would be to use something like [Hangfire](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire), [Quartz.NET](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) or the built-in [QueueBackgroundworkItem](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2014/05/07/scheduling-background-jobs-from-an-asp-net-application-in-net-4-5-2). See Scott Hanselman's [blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx) for more details.

Comment: I resolved that issue adding thread.Join(3000); after thread.Start(); but thanks for the suggestions, I will read the articles you sent and try to improve my application.